# Does an instrument variable become exogenous if its values are random?

Tags: residuals, instrumental-variables, exogeneity

In order to use an instrument variable it has to be exogenous.

**My question:**
*Does IV become exogenous if its values have been randomized? Ex. finding people with diabetes by pulling names from resident register randomly.*

Exogenity as I understand it is when the variable does not correlate with the residuals. Basically the variable should not correlate with what is unexplained in the model.

If the values of the IV are random, then the chance of "pulling" a person with diabetes should not correlate with things like sugar intake.

Answer (score 1):

Exogeneity is defined as the absence of correlation between a random variable and $\pmb{\varepsilon}$ (**error term**) .

Note that a variable can be endogenous even though it might be uncorrelated with **residuals** (estimates of $\pmb{\varepsilon}$). For the following example, note that while the error term is expressed as $\pmb{\varepsilon}$, residuals will be represented by $\textbf{e}$.

Let us estimate the following Regression model:

$$\textbf{y} = \text{E}[\textbf{y}|\textbf{X}] + \pmb{\varepsilon}$$

For which the following assumptions hold:

- A.1: $\text{E}[\textbf{y}|\textbf{X}] = \textbf{X}\pmb{\beta} \,\,\,\,\,$ (linearity)
- A.2: $\Pr(\text{rank}(\textbf{X}) = K) = 1, \,\,\, \textbf{X} \in \mathfrak{R}^{n\times K} \,\, \,$ (no perfect multicollinearity)

Further assume that there exists some covariates $\textbf{W} \in \mathfrak{R}^{n \times p}$ that also explain some variability in $\textbf{y}$ but we did not include them in our specification (omitted variables).

OLS estimation minimizes the sum of squared residuals $\textbf{e}'\textbf{e}$, where the residual vector is $\textbf{e} \equiv \textbf{y} - \textbf{X}\textbf{b}$.

This yields the following FOC:

$$\textbf{X}'\textbf{X}\tilde{\pmb{\beta}} = \textbf{X}'\textbf{y}$$

Where $\tilde{\pmb{\beta}}$ is a running parameter, different from the true parameter $\pmb{\beta}$ and the OLS estimator $\textbf{b}$. Only when $\tilde{\pmb{\beta}}$ satisfies the first-order conditions it becomes $\textbf{b}$.

Then:

$$\begin{align} \textbf{X}'\textbf{y} - \textbf{X}'\textbf{X}\textbf{b} & = \textbf{0} \\
\textbf{X}'(\textbf{y} - \textbf{X}\textbf{b}) & = \textbf{0} \\ 
\textbf{X}'\textbf{e} & = \textbf{0} \,\,\,\, \normalsize (\text{since} \,\, \textbf{e} = \textbf{y} - \textbf{X}\textbf{b})\end{align}$$

These are called the Normal Equations and show that $\textbf{X}$ is uncorrelated with the **residuals**. However, since $\textbf{W}$ is a relevant matrix of covariates that was not included in our specification, omitted variable bias arises and so we know that $\text{Cov}(\textbf{X}, \pmb{\varepsilon}) \neq \textbf{0}$. Consequently, $\textbf{X}$ is uncorrelated with the residuals but not with the error term, namely, $\textbf{X}$ is endogenous even though $\text{Cov}(\textbf{X}, \textbf{e}) = \textbf{0}$.

Having cleared that out, note that there **two** assumptions required for an instrumental variable to be valid: exogeneity and relevance. It is also vital that such instrumental variable affects the dependent variable **only** through the endogeneous variable.

In your example only one of these assumptions is satisfied (exogeneity). Nevertheless, it is pretty unlikely that certain names are correlated with any factor you might be interested in studying its casual effect on diabetes (lack of relevance).

Assume there are available some instrumental variables $\textbf{z}_i$ for each of the endogeneous regressors $\textbf{x}_i$ such that we have #exogenous variables = #regressors. It goes without saying that $\text{E}[\textbf{z}_i\varepsilon_i] = \textbf{0}$ should hold.

Our model still satisfies linearity and no perfect multicollinearity, thus:

$$y_i = \textbf{x}_i'\pmb{\beta} + \varepsilon_i$$

Multiply by $\textbf{z}_i$ on both sides and take expectations:

$$\begin{align} \text{E}[\textbf{z}_iy_i] & = \text{E}[\textbf{z}_i\textbf{x}_i']\pmb{\beta} + \textbf{E}[\textbf{z}_i\varepsilon_i] \\
\text{E}[\textbf{z}_iy_i] & = \text{E}[\textbf{z}_i\textbf{x}_i']\pmb{\beta} \\
\pmb{\beta} & = (\text{E}[\textbf{z}_i\textbf{x}_i'])^{-1}\text{E}[\textbf{z}_iy_i] \end{align}$$

It is needed to assume that $\text{E}[\textbf{z}_i\textbf{x}_i']$ is nonsingular (invertible).

Note that if $\text{Cov}(\textbf{z}_i, \textbf{x}_i) = \textbf{0}$, then we are in trouble since $\pmb{\beta}$ could not be estimated (we would be 'dividing' by zeros!).

This is precisely what happens in your example. Your instrument might be exogenous, but I doubt it is relevant.